# Trying to search JSON for a particular value in a field that is not always there

Tags: php, json, search, field

I have the below JSON Array, and I am after one particular value in a uniqueID object. The thing is that this field is not always there as it is an object off a field.

The one I am after is 'Kn04'

```
{
  "searchMeta": {
    "maxResults": 100,
    "sourceId": "6e5c1d5d-d84b-4b64-9d2c-a32b8c9f7174",
    "iso8601Timestamps": true,
    "sourceType": "VENUE",
    "endTimestamp": 1444952156,
    "startTimestamp": 1444952056
  },
  "ranges": [
    {
      "clients": [
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "6c:19:8f:bf:47:e9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -93.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "Kn04"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -75.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:75:95:0e"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -86.2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "44:d9:e7:21:e0:de"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -25.8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:26"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -47
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:29"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -72.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "a4:ee:57:2e:ac:bd"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -95
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "CQos"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -64.1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "86:8f:c2:8f:c3:20"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -68.4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "32:91:8f:6c:2e:f4"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "30:91:8f:6c:2e:f3"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -86.9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "30:91:8f:43:ca:49"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "1d:8b:90:7b:20:9c"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -102.5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "38:2c:4a:5c:b6:a0"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -76.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "ECgg"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -59.5
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2015-10-15T23:35:00+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I have so far is below, but it does not work. $response is the JSON array name

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);


foreach($json['ranges'] as $range){
foreach($range['clients'] as $client)
foreach($client['clientId'] as $client1 => $device)
{
    if($device['uniqueId'] == "Kn04")
    {
        echo $device=>uniqueId;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Why didn't you place bracket { after second loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `json_decode()` will return an array and not an object, because if `$assoc`  is set to `true`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Read this [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode)

At this level of your loop:

```
foreach($client['clientId'] as $client1 => $device)
```

The $device already refers to the uniqueId, so instead of:

```
 if($device['uniqueId'] == "Kn04")
```

You just need to write:

```
if($device== "Kn04")
```

And I can't figure out why would you display the value of uniqueId which is Kn04, since you know it, so maybe instead of that:

```
echo $device;
```

Add all in a function and return a `true` or `false` response

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);

function findDevice($id) {
    global $json;
    foreach($json['ranges'] as $range) {
        foreach($range['clients'] as $client) {
            foreach($client['clientId'] as $client1 => $device) {    
                if($device==$id) return true; // or return sthing else
            }
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: This one did not do anything as far as I could see. I changed the return for echo to test it and nothing was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a recursive function you could use. The cool thing about recursive search is that it doesn't care about the array structure. If more levels come up later - you won't have to change anything. Also - I don't see why you would want to print the known id so in my example it prints the whole device

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);

function findRecursive($array, $needle){

    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $key => $item){

            if($item === $needle){
                return $array;
            }

            $found = findRecursive($item, $needle);

            if($found != false){
                return $found;
            }
        }
    } else return false;
}

$device = findRecursive($json, 'Kn04');

if($device) {
    print_r($device);
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

EDIT: The next example allows you to select sourceIds with values greater than a threshold argument

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);

function matchSidsByThresholdRecursive($array, $treshold, &$results){

if(is_array($array)){

    //If this is the array we are looking for - it has to have both 'sourceId' and 'value' indexes
    if(isset($array['sourceId']) && isset($array['value'])){
        //The current value is greater than threshold? Add the corresponding sourceId to results
        if($array['value'] > $treshold){
            $results[] = $array['sourceId'];
        }
    }

    //If one of the subitems is an array - iterate through it the same way
    foreach($array as $item){
        if(is_array($item)){
            matchSidsByThresholdRecursive($item, $treshold, &$results);    
        }                        
      }
    }     
}

$results = array();

//This will populate the $results array with sourceIds with the values greater than -50
matchSidsByThresholdRecursive($json, -50, $results);

if($results) {
    print_r($results);
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks amazing. Hey, question please? Can I also check to make sure the value field is greater than a certain value as well (say>-80)?, then return value in the associated sourceId field as well? If you could help with that it would be incredible. Thanks. Rob

Comment: Rob, check out the answer update - should do what you need

Comment: Hi Parshin, I tried the first one and it says error Warning: include(web/404.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The thing is there is no line 27. it is in between these two Line 26   $json = json_decode($response,true);      and  Line 28

function findRecursive($array, $needle){   thanks

Comment: Has to be something wrong with the other parts of your script - it tries to include the error handler html, but fails to find the 404 html file. Not sure why it does that...